# Safely tripping a newly bought circuit breaker to make sure it works

Tags: safety, circuit-protection, testing

As the title suggests. I recently bought two circuit breakers as a means of protection for a little project of mine. One's a 60A, and the other's an 80A. I've already tested it to make sure that power does flow through when it's "on" and that it breaks the circuit when manually shut off via a button on the breaker. What I haven't done yet is stress tested it to make sure the breaker will trip when overloaded, and I was curious if anyone had some safe suggestions for how to go about it.

What would be an ideal method?
what would be an ideal power source?
What would be an ideal location to perform the test?
What would be recommended to have on hand should things go south?

Comment: Nice question and I would be curious to know how to safely test that, but in practice: I guess unless the application is extremely critical, the ideal would be to buy stuff from where you can trust the specs and not have to characterize every single scenario?

Comment: That should be done on special equipment at special place. Why don't you trust the manufacturer? It must have some means and procedure for quality control. Even you do it by yourself it is not for sure it works properly in future use.

Comment: Have a look for switchgear current injection testing. I think you'll want a 100:5 current transformer and run it in reverse from a variac with something in the variac circuit to limit the current to 5 A max. The question sounds as though you have no confidence in the devices purchased. If that's the case testing them gives you only a very short-term confidence.

Comment: If they have an ETL mark on them (like UL) then you can look at the certifications on them (IEC) and see to what standards they have been tested. If they don't have a mark\certs, I wouldn't use the equipment. We have ETL's so we don't have to do this kind of testing. Also, many (good) manufacturers also do testing to make sure their devices conform.

Comment: If homebrew testing for whatever reason, read the spec / standard carefully. The actual momentary current at which it trips might be a lot higher than the nominal figure (ie there's an element of time also).

Comment: It has been tested and it's worth noting that tripping causes wear, especially with extreme testing.  In practice, a 90A or 100A heater will fairly reliably blow an 80A breaker although it can take a bit of time.  It's worth noting I know that because of wrong breakers being installed, not because it's a standard method of testing.  For practical testing with minimal damage you probably want to repeat the same type of tests it's already been subected to.  Possibly hire someone who has the equipment as mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

If the voltage is 6, 12, 18 or 24 VDC you might use a pack of battery in parallel.

Lead acid batteries will do:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/batteries-rechargeable-secondary/91?s=N4IgTCBcDaIDYFMCGATABEgxgS3QRjDQDc0AjJAFwoQCcBPEAXQF8g